__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
Flutter app iOS build on testflight is crashing on startup
Is it the issue of xcode or firbase? as the app is runnig fine in android and also when i try to run with on iphone with cable connected.
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  nanopb                         0x6904 (Missing UUID e9aced830a573caeb1bdf26f2ffb057a)
1  nanopb                         0x6074 (Missing UUID e9aced830a573caeb1bdf26f2ffb057a)
2  FirebaseSessions               0x413c (Missing UUID e815ba4277133b98ad7c14e74db42ad9)
3  FirebaseSessions               0xef10 (Missing UUID e815ba4277133b98ad7c14e74db42ad9)
4  FirebaseSessions               0xf198 (Missing UUID e815ba4277133b98ad7c14e74db42ad9)
5  GoogleDataTransport            0xdfd0 (Missing UUID 69a84be607ff3d86b879931321a6ba35)
6  GoogleDataTransport            0xde60 (Missing UUID 69a84be607ff3d86b879931321a6ba35)
7  GoogleDataTransport            0x1b070 (Missing UUID 69a84be607ff3d86b879931321a6ba35)
8  FirebaseSessions               0xa74c (Missing UUID e815ba4277133b98ad7c14e74db42ad9)
9  FirebaseSessions               0x5efc (Missing UUID e815ba4277133b98ad7c14e74db42ad9)
10 FirebaseSessions               0x5f80 (Missing UUID e815ba4277133b98ad7c14e74db42ad9)
11 FirebaseSessions               0xd0c8 (Missing UUID e815ba4277133b98ad7c14e74db42ad9)
12 FirebaseSessions               0xd2c8 (Missing UUID e815ba4277133b98ad7c14e74db42ad9)
13 FirebaseSessions               0xaafc (Missing UUID e815ba4277133b98ad7c14e74db42ad9)
14 FirebaseSessions               0xa9c0 (Missing UUID e815ba4277133b98ad7c14e74db42ad9)
15 FirebaseInstallations          0x49c0 (Missing UUID fed1161227cb3f15ad6f3ba5ff68d197)
16 FBLPromises                    0x5138 (Missing UUID 28c5491659603b608d06d414f996dcd7)
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x213c _dispatch_call_block_and_release
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x3dd4 _dispatch_client_callout
19 libdispatch.dylib              0x125ec _dispatch_main_queue_drain
20 libdispatch.dylib              0x121b8 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
21 CoreFoundation                 0x3751c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
22 CoreFoundation                 0x34218 __CFRunLoopRun + 1996
23 CoreFoundation                 0x33968 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
24 GraphicsServices               0x34e0 GSEventRunModal + 164
25 UIKitCore                      0x22aedc -[UIApplication _run] + 888
26 UIKitCore                      0x22a518 UIApplicationMain + 340
27 Runner                         0x8f0c main + 10 (AppDelegate.swift:10)
28 ???                            0x1b3802d84 (Missing)


I don't use Flutter, but I had the same issue on iOS. Switching to the latest versions of Firebase libs seems to fix the issue for me.

yeah, it has something to do with the firebase version below 10.20.0
